# Waiting for batch-end

Tags: java, batch-file, runtime.exec

I have 4 lines in my `bat` file, but my thread goes on before the cmd closes.

Here's my code:

```
rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
proc = rt.exec("cmd /c start C:\\temp\\test.bat");
if(proc.waitFor() == 0) {
    return "did it";
} else {
    return "nooope";
}
```

I always get the `did it` before cmd closes. 
Here is my batch-file:

```
@ECHO off
taskkill /IM "Process.exe" /F
cd "C:\Program Files\ProcessFolder"
START /WAIT Process.exe
START otherProcess.exe
EXIT
```

any help?

Comment: You should explain or add why you don't want to use threading in your java code and what else comes after your main code. Finding problems without knowing the thread situation of your program is painful because the main thread might end or could be interrupted. So it would be good to post a reduced program which could reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also look at the article linked from the [`runtime.exec` Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info).  Implement the recommendations for most robust use of a `Process`.  Also note that Java has had `ProcessBuilder` since 1.5.  It is better than using `exec` - one reason is that it makes it easy to consume both output streams (mentioned in the linked article).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're using `start` - which will start a *new* shell in which to run the batch file. The original shell then closes, so the process terminates, and your Java program continues.

Remove the `start` and it should work, in terms of waiting for the batch file to end. However, you've then got the same problem again within the batch file when you start `otherProcess`.

Either don't use `start`, or *always* use `start /wait` within the batch file.

If you use `start /wait` within the Java code, however, you'll end up with a command prompt sitting there at the end of the batch file execution, as far as I can tell by experimentation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answer. The Problem what i have. I can't /wait for the otherProcess, because the Process is a Serverprocess which have to stay alive until the next call for the Program comes. By removing start from java, the batchfile wont run :-(

Comment: @Markus: "won't run" is very vague. What happens when you try? You won't see the batch file in a separate window, but it should work. If you don't want to wait for otherProcess, that's fine, so long as you're happy for the batch file to terminate and the Java code to continue.

Comment: "Wont run" will mean, that the process what normally had killed is staying alive, and no new process starts like before with "start" in java.

Comment: @Markus: I'm afraid I didn't follow that at all - but you certainly *can* run a batch file using `cmd /c path\to\file.bat`. I just did it.

Comment: Sry for doublepost. w/o start in java will work. I entered a wrong batch-filename :-/ Now, that works. Thanks for the Help, you're very good :-)